# Is hydra.iohk.io just down or has there been a change in .json configs’ provisioning?

Tags: testnet, mainnet, topology, json

Where does one get the basic `.*-config.json`, `.*-topology.json` and `.*-genesis.json` files for package building nowadays? The URLs that always worked for me seem down, e.g.:

https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/mainnet-config.json

This makes it quite hard to rebuild [this package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cardano-node) that [depends on the configs](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=cardano-node#n27). Somewhere on the interwebs they [mention](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/i-seem-to-be-stuck-because-a-binary-cache-is-down/23641/4) a switch from `hydra.iohk.io` to `cache.iog.io`, but nope, that doesn’t work either. (Or perhaps the URL structure is completely different.)

I could probably just reuse the files from `1.35.3` for `1.35.4`, but (sort of) dislike the idea; I like to keep things clean & correct & buildable long-term.

So what’s the issue here? Is it just temporary downtime? Has there been a change in the config file provisioning? Or have the config files themselves been replaced? (If so, is there a migration guide?) Looking at [the `1.35.4` release notes](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases/tag/1.35.4), I can’t spot any news concerning the `.json` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hydra.iohk.io site went through unexpected retirement (and may not be restored). But the release notes for 1.35.4 already have updated links for binary download (which points to update-cardano-mainnet.iohk.io) and configs (which points to https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html).

Also, the config files you download from that site are available on github [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-world/tree/master/docs/environments)

Comment: Well, the `cardano-world` repo doesn’t have tags, but I assume that the `1.35.4-node-bump` branch might do.  In retrospect, the reason why my vigorous GitHub searches found nothing was … the renaming of `mainnet-config.json` to `config.json`. That’s a level of encryption that my brain just could not penetrate.